# Getting a NaN when typing a value

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to calculate a value from 2 input boxes and then get the total of those input boxes. I'm then trying to get the all my amounts and total them and add them to the subtotal but the issue I'm having is that when I type in a number in the first box my output is `NaN` instead of 0 and I would like for it to show me a 0 instead.

Here is my code

```html
<template>
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Unit</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr v-for="product in products">
                                                <td>{{ product['name'] }}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="unit[product['unit']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="price[product['price']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {{ cost[product['name']] }}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    Subtotal: {{ subTotal }}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: [],
    data(){
        return {
            products: [],
            unit: {},
            price: {},
            cost: []
        }
    },
    computed:{
        subTotal(){
            if(this.cost!== null)
            {
                if(Object.keys(this.cost).length !== 0){
                    return  Object.keys(this.cost).reduce((carry, item) => {
                                carry+= Number(this.cost[item])
                                return carry;
                            }, Number(0))
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getProducts(){
            axios.get(`/api/product/all`).then(response => {
               this.products = response.data.products;
            });
        },
        calculateCost(item){
            this.cost[item] = Number(this.unit[item]) * Number(this.price[item]);
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getProducts();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try defining your input field type as a number.

Comment: also, this.fees does not exist.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I added the input field as number, but I still got NaN

Comment: It's working fine for me, can you share in which specific line you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all type of inputs return a string. You can use

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="unit[product['unit']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])">
```

or

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model.number="unit[product['unit']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])">
```

Comment: I tried both of those but I still got NaN

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `v-model` for `unit` and `price` are set to the different keys than the one given to `calculateCost()`, which causes the lookups to fail and results in `NaN`:

```html
<input v-model="unit[product['unit']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])"> ❌
                             ^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^
<input v-model="price[product['price']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])"> ❌
                              ^^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^

<input v-model="unit[product['name']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])"> ✅
<input v-model="price[product['name']]" @change="calculateCost(product['name'])"> ✅
```

Setting the keys to `product['name']` ensures the correct lookup for `unit` and `price` in `calculateCost()`. Since the user could enter invalid values (non-numeric strings) or omit a value, it's possible to get `NaN`, so it would be a good idea to add a `NaN`-check in `calculateCost()`:

```js
calculateCost(item) {
  const unit = Number(this.unit[item]);
  const price = Number(this.price[item]);
  if (Number.isNaN(unit) || Number.isNaN(price)) return;
  this.cost[item] = unit * price;
},
```

Also, you probably want the cost to react to user input, so switch from `@change` to `@input`:

```html
<input v-model="unit[product['name']]" @input="calculateCost(product['name'])">
<input v-model="price[product['name']]" @input="calculateCost(product['name'])">
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GRNyaPE)